# angular material mat-dialog getting can't

Tags: angular, typescript

I am calling a mat-dialog which call the angular service to get the data to bind to the UI. I have an interface as followed

```
export interface ViewModel {
  computations: ComputationData;
  explanation: Explanation;
  comments: string;
  requireMoreInformation: boolean;
}
```

I added the service call in the constructor and also tested in ngOnInit

```
Constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  this.myService.getData().subscribe(data => {
    if (data) {
      this.viewModelData = data;
      this.loadData();
    }
  }
}
```

When I bring up the mat-dialog popup, I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> and see that many of the objects which I use to bind to the UI are getting this type of message

> Cannot read property 'titles' of undefined

I started adding the following to the constructor and there are many to instantiate

```
this.viewModelData.computations = {} as ComputationData;
this.viewModelData.explanation = {} as Explanation;
```

In my regular components, I never have to initialize my property. I just needed to instantiate the object as this.viewModelData = []; When I get the data from the service, I set all the values and bind to the UI.

I places some breakpoints and noticed that the UI binding was being called before the data arrived back from the service.

Is there a way to bind to the UI after I get the data?

Answer (score 0):

You could expose the view model data as an observable and use the async pipe but that might be complicated.

You could also hide the content of the dialog with an `ngIf` that is gated whether or not `viewModelData` is `null` or `undefined`.  You could even have it display a spinner when `viewModelData` isn't loaded.

Those are the methods that jump to mind but what you are describing is pretty normal.  You mention you've been able to get away with it so far but you also mention...

`this.viewModelData = [];`

If your data is an *array* then you probably have an `ngFor` in your view which simply has zero elements.  This is doing the same thing as a wrapping `*ngIf`.  You don't actually have any view elements trying to grab bits of view model data until your view model is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't see performance issues in your own testing, in an asynchronous environment, you cannot always predict when data might be delayed.

Generally, I gate all my displays by checking if the object is defined using `ngIf`. If it's not defined, I display a component that shows some type of loading message or animated graphic (or both).

The alternative is that you fetch the data before you load the dialog, but even in that situation, you may have to display some type of loading message.